# Node Express - multer causing controller call failure and vice versa

Tags: express, multer

**Routes.js**

The below code worked.

```
var upload= multer({ storage: storage})
app.post('/upload', [ upload.any(), function(req, res) {
     console.log(req.body) // form fields
     console.log(req.files) // form files
     res.status(204).end()
   }]);
```

However, I wanted to call a controller method as well which is located in my file `uploadController.js`

So I did this, down below.

```
 app.post('/upload', controllers.uploadFiles.upload, [ upload.any(), function(req, res) {
                    console.log(req.body) // form fields
                    console.log(req.files) // form files
                    res.status(204).end()
                }]);
```

However, what happened was that my controller was called but then uploading part failed, i.e the below part wasn't called.

```
console.log(req.body) // form fields
 console.log(req.files) // form files
 res.status(204).end()
```

In conclusion, either one of them (multer or controller) work, both of them don't. 
   What could be wrong with this?

**UPDATE**

Tried the below. Only controller gets called. No file uploading done.

```
  app.post('/upload', controllers.dataUpload.upload, [ upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {
                    console.log(req.body) // form fields
                    console.log(req.files) // form files
                    next()
                }]);
```

Comment: It is a single route match? I was assuming there were two route matches. Can you post what's inside `controllers.dataUpload.upload`? Are you sure you are not terminating the execution in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't called `next` from the first controller. The execution ends after you call `res.end()`. If you want the execution to continue to the next route match, you must call `next()` on the first middle-ware.

You can read more about routing and middlewares in the guide: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Here are some quotes that might be relevant:

You need to call the `next` function so that the next controller is called:

> More than one callback function can handle a route (make sure you specify the next object).

When you call methods on the `res` object, the execution is terminated and the next controller is ignored:

> The methods on the response object (res) in the following table can send a response to the client, and terminate the request-response cycle. If none of these methods are called from a route handler, the client request will be left hanging.

Comment: Like this?
 app.post('/upload', controllers.uploadFiles.upload, [ upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {
                    console.log(req.body) // form fields
                    console.log(req.files) // form files
                    next()
                }]);`
`

Comment: Yup. Also take care of the order the controllers are defined in. The controllers are called in the same order they are defined in.

Comment: Please check my edited answer. It still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @squgeim for helping me out with the conceptual part. According to his guidance, I figured out the issue. Below is the working code.

**Routes.js**

```
var uploadStorage = multer({ storage: storage})
app.post('/upload', controllers.uploadController.uploadFile, [uploadStorage.any(), function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body) // form fields
    console.log(req.files) // form files
    res.status(204).end()
}]);
```

**uploadController.js**

```
module.exports = {
    uploadFile: (req, res, next) => {

        //Do whatever you want over here.
        next()
    },
}
```

So basically, inside `app.post` argument #2, I call the controller, do whatever I want and then call `next()` to proceed forward to `app.post` arguments #3 which is calling multer and uploading file.